# Rank of an Involutory Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

What is the rank of an $n \times n$ matrix that is it's own inverse. Does it always equal $n$?

Comment: If by "rank" you mean the dimension of the row space (equiv. of the column space) of a matrix, then it is well-known that to have an inverse requires full rank, i.e. rank = $n$ for an $n\times n$ matrix.  That would make the mention of being "[its] own inverse" superfluous.

Answer (score 6):

If a matrix has inverse its rank should be $n$.